# Show that if $\vert Y \vert \le c$ a.s. then $ \vert E\{Y |G\}\vert \le c$ a.s. also.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I was trying to prove that if $\vert Y \vert \le c$ a.s. then $ \vert E\{Y |G\}\vert  \le c$ a.s. also by contradiction.

If I assume $\vert Y \vert \le c$ a.s and $P(\vert E\{Y |G\}\vert  > c)>0$ then

$P(\vert E\{Y |G\}\vert  > c,c\ge \vert Y \vert)>0$ since  $\vert Y \vert \le c$ a.s. and we can conclude that $P(\vert E\{Y |G\}\vert  >\vert Y \vert)>0$.

Another alternate idea that I had was
Since conditional expectation  E{Y |G} takes the values $E[Y\mathbb{1}_A]$ as $A$ varies in $G$ we can conclude that
$Y\mathbb{1}_A \le Y \le \vert Y \vert \le c $ we have that for all $A$ in $G$ we have $E[Y\mathbb{1}_A] \le c$ and hence  $\vert E\{Y |G\} \vert \le E\{\vert Y \vert |G\} \le c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argumentgs don't seem rigorous. For  a correct proof you have to use the definition of conditional expectation. Let $Z=E[Y|\mathcal G]$. By definition $\int_AZdP=\int_A YdP$ for all $A \in \mathcal G$. Let $A=\{Z >c\}$. If $P(A) >0$ then $c P(A) <\int_A Z dP =\int_A YdP \leq cP(A)$ which is a contradiction. This proves that $P(A)=0$ so $Z \leq c $ a.s.. Similarly $Z >-c$ a.s.

Comment: But why is $c \mathbb{1}_{Z>c} < Z  \mathbb{1}_{Z>c}$  for $\omega \in \{Z \le c\}$? Dont we need this inequality to hold for all $\omega$ to be able to apply the expectation? For  $\omega \in \{Z \le c\}$ we will get $0<0$ which isnt true. Sorry if its a stupid question

Comment: @user3503589 Suppose $X>Y$ on $A$ and $X \geq Y$ on $A^{c}$ where $P(A) >0$. The $E X>EY$. This is because $E(X-Y) \geq E((X-Y)I_A>0$. We don't need strict inequality on $A^{c}$.

Comment: ah thanks a lot